# cmake how to append compiler flags to the end in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, standards, compiler-flags

I want set compiler C++ standard to gnu++17 but I cant do that with `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` as it gives me `gnu++17` is invalid value.Thus I put it in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` .  But when I compile cmake appends `std=gnu++11` to the end of command like this:-

```
/bin/g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -std=gnu++14 -no-pie   -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -o /path/to/main.cpp.o -c /blah/blahfeeelk
```

thus `std=gnu++11` win  . So want to append `gnu++17` to the end .
How can I do that ?
(I have trimmed the original command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake has three variables to control the version of the C++ standard and switching compiler extensions on/off. I’m showing the target specific versions here because that is how it should be used in reasonably modern (v3.x) CMake.

```
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    CXX_EXTENSIONS ON
)
```

This enables C++17, prevents automatic fallback to an earlier standard if 17 is not available, and enables compiler extensions. For GCC this is equivalent to `-std=gnu++17` or `-std=gnu++1z`.

[CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) with the `17` value is available since CMake 3.8. [CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED) and [CXX_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS) exist since CMake 3.1.

Comment: This only works for std versions whitelisted by cmake.
It does NOT work for c++2a. A solution for this would be nice (since something keeps adding `-std=gnu++11` flag in my case)